# JavaScript - Group CSV fields based on empty cells

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, csv, javascript-objects

I have data that come from a CSV file that can have blank fields and must have data grouped based on that.

Here's a simple example of a data of persons by location. The location data only appears for the first person and every following person that don't have a location assigned belongs to the location that comes before:

```js
"Objects:", [{
    location: "New York",
    date: "10/10/2021",
    name: "Max",
    surname: "Payne"
}, {
    location: "",
    date: "",
    name: "Duke",
    surname: "Nuken"
}, {
    location: "",
    date: "",
    name: "Jack",
    surname: "Carver"
}, {
    location: "Las Vegas",
    date: "30/10/2021",
    name: "Leon",
    surname: "Kennedy"
}, {
    location: "",
    date: "",
    name: "Donkey",
    surname: "Kong"
}, {
    location: "",
    date: "",
    name: "Ryu",
    surname: "Hayabusa"
}]
```

I need to join the list of persons into a list and add it to the corresponding location:

```js
"Objects:", [{
    location: "New York",
    date: "10/10/2021",
    persons: [{
        name: "Max",
        surname: "Payne"
    }, {
        name: "Duke",
        surname: "Nuken"
    }, {
        name: "Jack",
        surname: "Carver"
    }]
}, {
    location: "Las Vegas",
    date: "30/10/2021",
    persons: [{
        name: "Leon",
        surname: "Kennedy"
    }, {
        name: "Donkey",
        surname: "Kong"
    }, {
        name: "Ryu",
        surname: "Hayabusa"
    }]
}]
```

The data originally comes as an array of arrays in this form:

```js
const [headers, ...lines] = [
    ["location",  "date",       "name",   "surname" ],
    ["New York",  "10/10/2021", "Max",    "Payne"   ],
    ["",          "",           "Duke",   "Nuken"   ],
    ["",          "",           "Jack",   "Carver"  ],
    ["Las Vegas", "30/10/2021", "Leon",   "Kennedy" ],
    ["",          "",           "Donkey", "Kong"    ],
    ["",          "",           "Ryu",    "Hayabusa"],
];
```

The code I currently have to convert the array into the first list of objects in this question  is this:

```js
const locations = lines.map( (line) =>
   line.reduce((object, value, index) =>
        ({...object, [ headers[index] ]: value})
      , {}
   ));
```

What would be a good way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's an example using [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and hard coding the header names.

```js
const
  [headers, ...lines] = [["location", "date", "name", "surname"], ["New York", "10/10/2021", "Max", "Payne"], ["", "", "Duke", "Nuken"], ["", "", "Jack", "Carver"], ["Las Vegas", "30/10/2021", "Leon", "Kennedy"], ["", "", "Donkey", "Kong"], ["", "", "Ryu", "Hayabusa"],],

  result = lines.reduce((a, [location, date, name, surname]) => {
    if (location && date) a.push({ location, date, persons: [] });

    a[a.length - 1].persons.push({ name, surname });

    return a;
  }, []);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Here is a more dynamic example allowing you to specify 'requiredIndeces' that should be present to group by. You can adjust for your particular needs.

```js
const
  input = [["location", "date", "name", "surname"], ["New York", "10/10/2021", "Max", "Payne"], ["", "", "Duke", "Nuken"], ["", "", "Jack", "Carver"], ["Las Vegas", "30/10/2021", "Leon", "Kennedy"], ["", "", "Donkey", "Kong"], ["", "", "Ryu", "Hayabusa"],],

  refactorCSV = (arr, requiredIndeces) => {
    const
      reduceByRequiredIndex = (arr) => arr.reduce((a, x, i) =>
        (a[+requiredIndeces.includes(i)].push(x), a), [[], []]),
      [headers, ...lines] = arr,
      [entryProps, requiredProps] = reduceByRequiredIndex(headers);

    return lines.reduce((a, line) => {
      const [personValues, requiredValues] = reduceByRequiredIndex(line);

      if (requiredValues.every(v => v !== '')) {
        const required = {};
        requiredProps.forEach((prop, i) => required[prop] = requiredValues[i]);

        a.push({ ...required, persons: [] });
      }

      const person = {};
      entryProps.forEach((prop, i) => person[prop] = personValues[i]);

      a[a.length - 1].persons.push(person);

      return a;
    }, []);
  },

  result = refactorCSV(input, [0, 1]);

console.log(JSON.stringify(result, null, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: That's a good one! Unfortunately in my use case I believe the headers can vary, for example, I can have the person birth-date or age, or have another field more in the city.